# Adding attributes to xmlNode in Axapta 2012

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012, xml-attribute

Can we add attributes to xmlNode in Axapta 2012? If so, how do I do this?

Below is my XML. I need to add an Id attribute to the `<Task>` node.

```xml
<Task Id="Cs-2213">
    <Name>Cannot delete the picking lists (lines)</Name>
    <Version>6.2.1000.4051</Version>
    <Sprint>17.8</Sprint>
    <Project>Cs2213_Prd_DelPickIssue</Project>
    <Area>Production</Area>
    <Status>Closed</Status>
    <BugTrackId/>
</Task>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `XmlElement.setAttribute` method to add attributes to an XML node. So for example if `xmlElement` is the `Task` XML node, the code would be

```
xmlElement.setAttribute('Id', 'Cs-2213');
```

See also [XmlElement.setAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xmlelement.setattribute.aspx) Method [AX 2012] (MSDN documentation of the method) and [Create XML and write to file in Dynamics AX](https://axzaptech.wordpress.com/2010/11/24/create-xml-and-write-to-file-in-dynamics-ax/) (complete example and first Google result for "dynamics ax xml attributes")